# How can I call class in class?

Tags: java, class, oop

I'm trying something that like calling class in class, but every time I failed.
Think about, I have 2 class and 1 main .java file, all of them in the same package.

- I have a array in x class. you can imagine this array like "rooms in hotel" or "seats on bus".
- In this way, x class will be hotel or bus.
- The y class is "buyers" or "passengers". They have a account page, they can log into the site, etc..
- So, in main class, I created y objects.
- I also created in y class buyRoom() method (its the question)

When I buy X's rooms, in array filled up with y's name or y's account ID.

Which method should I use for buyRoom() or buySomething() method?

Mine has a vip and regular seats:

```
public Reservation(int seat, boolean reservationType){
count++;
code+=count;
if(reservationType==true){
    vipSeats--;
}
else {
    regSeats--;
}
// seats[seat]=Passenger.getName(); <-- is it works?


}
```

Comment: `Class A` can call `Class B` in the same way your `main` class would call either one.  Beyond that... you're going to have to clarify what you're asking...

Comment: You have to instantiate the class first by calling its constructor i.e. you have to do `Passenger person = new Passenger();` Hopefully I didn't misinterpret your problem.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance nhgrif. i just want an example method for this usage.
i  already create an object Y aug

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @GökhanNas Do you know how to instantiate an object of `Class A` in your `main` class?  I don't understand how you need an example.  Instantiate a `class` is the same no matter what class you instantiate it in... if you don't need to instantiate a class, look for some very basic Java tutorials on OOP.

Comment: instantiate an object isn't creating an object? like "Class x = new Class()" ? I said that i created Y objects but I need Create a X objects in method in Y class.

**like when i type this = Y.createXObject();
**it will be created. But how can  do this  its my question.

Comment: I understand right now what is instantiate objects excatly. Thanks for help nhgrif. if you can write this info as my answer, i can apply this for my answer so others can see this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume that you have public First() and public Second(); two classes in the same folder. You can call public Second() in public First() and use function mean(int num), assuming that it's defined in Second() by using the following syntax:

```
Second a = new Second();
System.out.println(a.mean(5));
```